# Как спарсить три столбика валют?(Ошибка в коде сайт бестчендж)

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Тут хотела спарсить три столбика нужной валюты но возникает ошибка с третьим столбиком.Проблема в том, что ставишь цифру то парсит с одного места, когда ставишь переменную то парсить начинает и второй столбик получаетца каша.А еще как можно обернуть в ткинтер добавить?

```
    def bestchange():
        crip = "https://www.bestchange.ru/ripple-to-yoomoney.html"
        response = requests.get(crip, headers=headers).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parse')
        convert2 = soup.findAll("table", {"id" : "content_table"})
        convert2 = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "pc"}, {"class" : "ca"})
        convert = soup.findAll("td", {"class" : "bi"})
        convert3 = soup.findAll("td", {"class" : "bi"})#вот в этой перемменной все и ломаетца.
        con = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "intro"})
        print(con[0].text)
        for i in range(20):
            tro = convert2[i].text + "==" + convert[0].text + "==" + convert3[3].text #вот в этой перемменной все и ломаетца.
            print(tro)
        return bestchange()
    bestchange()
```

Как исправить вот эти две ошибки в коде?
1)Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html.parse. Do you need to install a parser library?
2)The code that caused this warning is on line 22 of the file C:\Users\Parser_valut_invest.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html')
3)list index out of range
Как решить эти ошибки!!
Вот эти 3 столбика пробую там 2 класса одинаковые!
https://prnt.sc/116phc7
и вот https://prnt.sc/116pih0
Ругаетца пайтон на вот эту строку
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parse')
делаю так :
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html')
работает но выдает ошибку и идет результат .
Пишу на пайчаре и саблайм-текст 3.

Comment: какие столбики нужно спарсить?

Comment: добавила в тему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас опечатка в названии парсера, не `html.parse`, а `html.parser`

Парсить таблицы сразу по ячейкам не стоит, лучше по строкам, а там уже разбирать ячейки.

Накидал [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8099e231d477fc78c88ff989fb769dedfa7f36fc/html_parsing/www_bestchange_ru.py#L14):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


rs = requests.get('https://www.bestchange.ru/ripple-to-yoomoney.html')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

for tr in root.select('#content_table > tbody > tr'):
    name = tr.select_one('td.bj .pc .ca').get_text(strip=True)

    [give_el, get_el] = tr.select('td.bi')
    give = give_el.select_one('.fs').get_text(strip=True)
    get = get_el.get_text(strip=True)

    print(name, give, get, sep=' | ')
```

Результат:

```
ChBy | 1 XRP | 67.3091RUB ЮMoney
BtcLider | 1 XRP | 67.0861RUB ЮMoney
CryptoHome | 1 XRP | 67.0227RUB ЮMoney
...
Ex-Bank | 1 XRP | 49.3700RUB ЮMoney
Crypto-Store | 1 XRP | 47.8860RUB ЮMoney
CoinStart | 1 XRP | 44.2528RUB ЮMoney
```

Comment: Благодарю,да ,увидела наверное когда копировала и дополняла забыла об р .Так я тоже пробывала пишет ошибку номер 2 у меня.Благодарю,ваш вариант кода лутше чем мой.

Comment: @аленакарпенко, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)